# Selenium Python How to wait for options in a select to be populated?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Example: To wait for

```
<select id="myselect"></select>
```

to be populated with

```
<option value="123">One-two-three</option>
```

How can I do it in Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `presence_of_element_located` and [explicit waiting](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to locate the element with a css selector:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "option[value='123']"))
    )
    print("Option loaded")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Time exceeded!")

#  Do Your Stuff
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. In the "finally", I print out the page_source, and that page is what I want. However, right after the page is printed out, there is one error message: 
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @jhhPhi Hey, I'm sorry, looks like I misused `finally` statement, this should do now. I'm glad it helped, also, if it was helpful and solved your issue, you should [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235), by clicking on the green marker near the upvotes.

Comment: "Time exceeded" printed out. Doesn't it mean within the given time, the statement never return true? Because it didn't return true, it catches TimeoutException, and then the code is continued. While the code was looping for 10 seconds, my page is already fully loaded, so I get the page I wanted. No?

Comment: @jhhPhi You are correct, it's not working as it should, let me see what's going on

Comment: @jhhPhi Please give it a try now.

Comment: It worked only after I delete "select#myselect > ". Turns out your first try was almost correct if you added a pair of single quote around the value. Thanks so much for solving my question.

Comment: For a specific Select you can modify like this
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#idOfYourSelect option[value=1]"))